# Weird Android Launcher Icon Issue

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest, launcher

I encountered a weird issue just on XHDPI devices with Android ver. 4.1

I have declared the application icon in AndroidManifest.xml, and put every size of icons(with the same name) I need on to drawable-xhdpi, drawble-hdpi and drawable-mdpi folders.

When I launch the application on mdpi (like Galaxy Ace) devices and hdpi (like Nexus One, Galaxy Ace II and emulators with Android ver. 2.2) it will display the correct icon I set.

But the icon will become wrong, I mean it will display the Green Android icon, when I am trying to launch it on my Galaxy Nexus (4.1) and Emulator(4.1).

[image: The weird icon]

I tried shut and reopen Eclipse, tried clean and rebuild the project, and I am sure the icon in every drawable folder is accessible (Can be opened and viewed).

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml:
NOTE: ic_launcher is the icon's name. I replace the default icon with mine.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="A"
            android:label="@string/a"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="B"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="C"
            android:label="@string/c"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="D"
            android:permission="android.permission.CAMERA"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="E"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="F" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All these devices are kept unroot and stick with the original stock system.

I went over nearly all of the SO's similar questions like:

[Android Launcher Icon not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546351/android-launcher-icon-not-working)

[App Launcher Icon Is Wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022579/app-launcher-icon-is-wrong)

[Wrong ic_launcher icon in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157668/wrong-ic-launcher-icon-in-my-app)

But still no luck.

Is there anybody get any idea with this? A bug in Android?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the -xhdpi folder just to see what happens? Or adding one into the standard drawable folder? Just trying to think of ways to observe its behavior.

Comment: Eh, you're using Eclipse, I'll chalk it up to that. I've had similar problems with it. I'd suggest renaming all your icons to something else (updating the manifest as well), then exit and relaunch Eclipse, clean, and rebuild. Then switch to IntelliJ. :)

Comment: @kcoppock thx, I just tried renaming all the icons, clean, rebuild and run, still the same issue...thats so annoying.

Comment: @dennisdrew actually your method works, thx. I moved the icon in xhdpi out, and restart Eclipse and run, the icon displayed correctly. But I'm not sure if it is the correct size on xhdpi devices.

Comment: @dennisdrew now I put the xhdpi icon in drawable (the folder without and qualifier), and the devices can display it. But why it not display the icon when i tried to put it in the xhdpi drawable folder?

Comment: Glad to hear that worked as a workaround. I'm not quite sure why it would do that...very strange behavior, especially considering you cleaned / rebuilt the project and everything. I guess there's a chance it's something wrong with the .png? You could try messing around with it using Android's Eclipse plugin for icon creation and see if that leads to the same result using a different icon.